# Unity3d: Remove the request for location permissions from your app if your target audience only includes children under 13

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-play, android-permissions, google-play-console

I have a game for kids on the Play Console. Play Store remove my game due to policy violation(*The target age groups you’ve selected are inaccurate. Make sure that you only select the appropriate age groups under 13 years old in your Target audience and content settings.*). Now I'm trying to remove the age group 13-15 but Play console won't let me to do this.

[image]

I'm facing this error "**You must remove the request for location permissions from your app if your target audience only includes children under 13**" when I'm trying to remove the age group 13-15.
I check the app package explorer on the Play Console and there is no permission for location.

[image]

Please let know how I can fix this issue.

I also added these lines in android manifest files but not working

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"
tools:node="remove" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" 
tools:node="remove"/>
```

I also remove the Google Admob ads SDK but issue remains the same

Comment: After reaching out to Google Play Developer Support, they provided a valuable solution to fix the problem.

The Google Play team investigated the situation further and found that one of the active APK versions (App Bundle Version: 20, Track: Open Testing, Version Name: 2.0) still contained the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission. They advised me to remove this permission from all active APK versions to comply with the policy for primarily targeting children. So, I fixed the issue by removing all other active version which requesting for location permission.

Comment: Great you found a solution on your own! Please add this as an answer to your own question (you can even accept it as a solution after 2 days) so that your question gains better visibility for people with the same issue

Comment: @derHugo Thank you very much for telling. I have added the solution in the answer section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reaching out to Google Play Developer Support, they provided a valuable solution to fix the problem.

Initially, I tried removing the age group 13-15, but encountered an error stating that I must also remove the request for location permissions from my app. I ensured that my app's manifest file did not include any location permissions, and even removed the Google AdMob ads SDK, but the issue persisted.

However, the Google Play team investigated the situation further and found that one of the active APK versions (App Bundle Version: 20, Track: Open Testing, Version Name: 2.0) still contained the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission. They advised me to remove this permission from all active APK versions to comply with the policy for primarily targeting children.

So, I fix the issue by removing the version 2.0 from open & close testing track which is requesting for location permission .